# How can I obtain the lowest level value in a nested, mix of arrays and objects using javascript destructuring

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

I'm new to destructuring and I'm doing ok but there is one final piece that I simply cannot work out.  I've searched all over for an answer/guidance but not found any that seem to fit my particular situation.  Go easy on me, I'm a novice!

I've got the following

```
{
"sunday": {
    "defaultSetpoint": 4,
    "heatingPeriods": [
        {
            "end": 30600,
            "start": 28800,
            "setpoint": 15.5
        }
    ]
},
"monday": {
    "defaultSetpoint": 4,
    "heatingPeriods": [
        {
            "end": 28500,
            "start": 27000,
            "setpoint": 15.5
        }
    ]
},
"tuesday": {
    "defaultSetpoint": 4,
    "heatingPeriods": [
        {
            "end": 28500,
            "start": 27000,
            "setpoint": 15.5
        }
    ]
},
"wednesday": {
    "defaultSetpoint": 4,
    "heatingPeriods": [
        {
            "end": 28500,
            "start": 27000,
            "setpoint": 15.5
        }
    ]
},
"thursday": {
    "defaultSetpoint": 4,
    "heatingPeriods": [
        {
            "end": 28500,
            "start": 27000,
            "setpoint": 15.5
        }
    ]
},
"friday": {
    "defaultSetpoint": 4,
    "heatingPeriods": [
        {
            "end": 28500,
            "start": 27000,
            "setpoint": 15.5
        }
    ]
},
"saturday": {
    "defaultSetpoint": 4,
    "heatingPeriods": [
        {
            "end": 30600,
            "start": 28800,
            "setpoint": 15.5
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I'm trying to get each end, start and setpoint for each day in the most efficient way.  I'm hoping destructuring will work.  So far my code is

```
let myObject = response
const {sunday: {heatingPeriods: [periodOne]}} = myObject;
```

Which gives me

```
Object {end: 30600, start: 28800, setpoint: 15.5}
```

But I cannot get end, start and setpoint and it's doing my nut!

Can anyone advise how to get these values please and also how to loop through the other days and do the same, catering for when there are more than one heating period in any day?

Many thanks in advance,

Matt

Comment: what do you mean with I cannot get end start and set point? what you did gives you a const variable called periodOne which is set to this object { end: 30600, start: 28800, setpoint: 15.5 } if you want to access e.g. attribute end just type periodOne.end try it out with console.log(periodOne.end)

Comment: And if you want to loop over all days you will need to know what output format you want to have. If you just want to access these values for a given day you can just type e.g. myObject.saturday.heatingPeriods[0].end

Comment: Thank you @charly1212, your assumptions are correct and you've answered my questions.  That's the way I was approaching it so it's good to corroborate that.  'Every day's a school day'!